# How can we find a contradiction?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, \rho)$ be a metric space and $x \in X, A \subset X (A \neq \varnothing)$. 
We have $x \in \overline{A}$ iff $d(x,A)=0$.

We suppose that $d(x,A)=0$ .

We want to show that $x \in \overline{A}$.

Suppose that $x \in X \setminus{ \overline{A}}$.

Since $X \setminus{ \overline{A}}$ is open, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\rho}(x, \epsilon) \subset X \setminus{ \overline{A}} \Rightarrow \{ y \in X: \rho(x,y)< \epsilon \} \subset X \setminus{\overline{A}}$.

How can we find a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if $y\in A$, $y$ is not in $\in X-\bar A$ thus $y$ is not in $B(x,\epsilon)$ so $d(x,y)\geq \epsilon$ $\forall y\in A$ and henceforth $d(x,A)\geq\epsilon>0$. Contradiction.